# Google Maps coordinates different than apple maps

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, mapkit

I am converting an Android app which uses Google Maps and the given longitude and latitude. I want to port the app to iOS and was thinking which maps system was better, either the native from Apple or the Google SDK. Apart from that I have some POI in Google which I would like to show also on the iOS equivalent.

Question is: Are the two coordinate system equal? So if I would put them on a map they would show the same location either on MapKit or Google Maps SDK.

Comment: Assume that you will use lat/lng on all platform (they are global value), the GPS accuracy and others stuffs are device-dependent. So don't expect your app gives you excactly the same thing on both devicea

Comment: The lat/long where taken from google maps and not an actual gps device. The problem is that when I am inserting them into apple maps they are off by 1km on the map. Shouldn't they point to the same location?

Comment: Hm I got it. It indeed a platform's problem :D

Answer (score 2):

sounds like the [China GPS shift problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_geographic_data_in_China#The_China_GPS_shift_problem) to me... otherwise, both Google Maps and Apple Maps (Tom Tom) should be in [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84).

Comment: So is there a solution for me or am I stuck with google maps?

Comment: if you are developing apps for china, you should be able to use one of the projects listed under [the GCJ-02 section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_geographic_data_in_China#GCJ-02)

Comment: No they are for Europe.

Comment: huh.. then it should have no problem. I also check multiple location in US and it seems to have no problem too. can you give a lat/lng for example?

Comment: I cannot post screenshots, I took the location where my current location in Greece is . The coordinates are from google maps (web site) and pasted them in apple maps on a mac. I tried also with a couple of POI and they were off by the same distance I suppose.

Comment: I tried [some locations](http://s28.postimg.org/qdfgzl2ax/Screen_Shot_2015_08_17_at_8_32_47_AM.jpg) and I do not see the difference you are mentioning. you can give a location (lat/lng) for a place where this is happening?

Comment: Yes I tried it again and now its working. I guess then it was a problem on the Public Beta of El Capitan which is fixed in the latest one now.